# $\mathbb{Q}[x,1/x]$ is normal?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $x$ be a transcendental.

I heard $\mathbb{Q}[x,1/x]$ is a  normal domain. But I don't understand why.

Help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1) Show that a UFD is a normal domain.

2) If $R$ is a normal domain, and $S \subseteq R$ is multiplicative, show that $S^{-1}R$ is a normal domain.

Alternatively, for this particular example, one can instead show that i) a PID is a normal domain, and ii) a localization of a PID is again a PID.

Comment: I got it! Thanks!

Comment: @user55871: You're welcome